# What terminal command shows the type of display that I have on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: display, macbook-pro

What terminal command shows the type of display that I have on my MacBook Pro?  I used the following command in terminal and it didn't work:

```
ioreg -lw0 | grep \"EDID\" | sed "/[^<]*
```

Comment: This command definitively will not work (the parameters to sed are wrong). Does `ioreg -lw0 | grep EDID` produce any results at all?

Comment: `ioreg -w0 -c IOHIDInterface` might be a bit closer, but it's going to be tricky to do this with shell commands, which are typically designed to handle line-wise records, not ascii-art-tree records.

Comment: No it does not.  I am completely new to the apple world. This is my first macbook.  I got the command from this article. http://m.tuaw.com/2012/08/14/are-retina-macbooks-displaying-screen-issues/?post=1&icid=tuaw_Mac_art

Comment: @Patrix: Yes it does show something, but not what i'm looking for. Thank you for you help.

Comment: @Ken: This gives me a lot of information. I will go thru it to see if it tells me that my screen is from LG or Samsung. Thank you for you assistance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ioreg -lw0 | grep \"EDID\" | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r | strings -6
```

Depending on the string that comes up it will tell you the manufacturer of the display. It will not display in plain text.

Assuming you have a Retina display, a string with LP in it means it's an LG.

Comment: The command doesn't seem to work with the new MacbookPro 13" Retina. Could anyone please check this? I'm encountering a display issue with my new mac :(

Comment: On my 13" non-Retina, it also **appears** to do nothing, the cmd returns without any output

Comment: I just learned about `xxd`. Cheers!

Comment: @ataulm On my MacBook Air, I had to remove grep's first `\"` for the command to return something.  Give it a try!  Now, the output string starts with `LTH`, wondering what display manufacturer it is...

Answer (score 2):

Does the relevant info show up in system profiler?

If so, there's a command line: system_profiler.  You can extract all kinds of information using the command line and piping it to cat, sed, awk, more, tail, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
ioreg -lw0 | grep "IODisplayEDID" | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r | strings -6
```

As 2022/Monterey OS the string need to be updated to "IODisplayEDID".

Answer (score 1):

If you have a problem identifying the display with the command described above (as I did), you may use the following approach.

Issue the command:

ioreg -lw0 |grep EDID |grep 4c534e

If you see nothing, it means the display is NOT Samsung (4C534E in hex is "LSN").
If you see several lines including some letter-digit mixture (hex), your display IS Samsung.

You may alternatively try to search for "4C50" (which is "LP" in hex), it WILL produce some output for LG and will produce nothing for Samsung:

ioreg -lw0 |grep EDID |grep 4c50

Or, you may just use the command

ioreg -lw0 |grep EDID

and manually look for the above fragments (4c534e for Samsung and 4c50 for LG) in its output.

Rationale: at least in the terminal you can get booting with "Command" held (e.g. before activation of MacOS on a new device), the "xxd" tool is not available.