# What's the horizontal sync and vertical refresh values for the June 2012 MBP 13" display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Got the June 2012 13" base MBP, and wondering if anyone knew (or how to find out) the **horizontal sync and vertical refresh** values for this display?

I'm trying to set up the correct resolution for the Linux Mint partition, and I've found with other installations (on other hardware) that having the incorrect hsync and vert refresh values will prevent the OS from listing all the available resolution options.

I rang and asked Apple Support but they weren't able to assist in this matter, but suggested that there might be a command to query the hardware directly.

edit: I tried the command listed at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61087/what-terminal-command-shows-the-type-of-display-that-i-have-on-my-macbook-pro) but it seemed to produce no output, and returned immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get these values by booting into the Linux partition (which somehow managed to get the correct resolution by itself!) and using the following cmd in terminal (requires super):

```
get-edid | parse-edid
```

I was expecting a range of values, e.g. `60.0 - 75.0`, but got the exact values - vfreq 60.223Hz and hfreq 50.949Hz.

This should be available via a live-CD/usb too.